# wpautop filter off for pages but on for posts

Tags: posts, wp-autop

I have the wpautop on remove filter for my pages but would like to turn it on just for posts and was wondering how to go about that. I'm newish to wordpress and can't figure out how to get this to work.

UPDATE: I found a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26571012/4443707

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your functions.php file

```
function disable_wpautop_for_pages(){
   if ( is_page()){
       remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
   }
}
 add_action('init', 'disable_wpautop_for_pages');
```

I have not tried this. It's just a guess

Comment: thank you it didn't work, but i did find a solution